# Does nohup apply only to a child process of a shell process, but not to a child process of a non-shell process?

Tags: nohup, sighup

nohup is an external program. How can it change the action of SIGHUP by a child process of a shell process to be "ignore"? (in terms of some arguments when the child process invokes `fork()` and/or `execve()` on the program which follows nohup?)

Does nohup apply only to a child process of a shell process, but not to a child process of a non-shell process?

Thanks.

Comment: nohup itself is the child process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nohup` configures itself to ignore the `SIGHUP` signal; see for example [the GNU implementation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/nohup.c?id=ece7157933fea925da10b5c3e7ace1f0fb2d9f50#n215). [The POSIX specification for `nohup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html) states that

> At the time the named *utility* is invoked, the SIGHUP signal shall be set to be ignored.

As also [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html#tag_16_111_03), child processes inherit ignored signals other than `SIGCHLD`, so any process started by `nohup` after it’s ignored `SIGHUP` will itself ignore `SIGHUP`.

`nohup`’s handling applies to any child of `nohup`, regardless of `nohup`’s parent process. `nohup` does *not* (nor can it) affect the way signals are handled by any of its parents, whether they’re shells or not.

Comment: Thanks. "child processes inherit ignored signals other than SIGCHLD, so any process started by nohup after it’s ignored SIGHUP will itself ignore SIGHUP." Is this specified as some argument to `execve()`?

Comment: No, it’s how all the `exec` functions are specified, in all cases. There is no `exec` argument you can use to change that.

Comment: Is it that way only for implementing nohup?

Comment: I suspect that `nohup` was taken into consideration when that part of POSIX was written, but it wasn’t the only consideration; see the rationale section on `exec` for details.

Comment: Thanks. Guru Stephen, may I call your attention to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484344/is-sighup-sent-to-this-orphaned-process-and-why-doesnt-it-terminate